# Ширина блоков, фиксированный шириной и резиновой?

Tags: css3, jquery, html, css, javascript

Есть блок. Его ширина 80% страницы.
В этом блоке, 2 блока один маленький, другой большой. 
Задача:
Фиксировать маленький.
Оставшееся место залить большим блоком.
Как!?

Comment: Предоставьте ваш код со стилями ,пожалуйста

Answer (score 3):

[Резиновый двухколоночный макет](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/tipovye-makety/rezinovyi-dvukhkolonochnyi-maket).

> Двухколоночный резиновый макет позволяет эффективно использовать площадь браузера, и вместе с тем достаточно удобен для самого широкого круга задач. Кроме того, такой макет не требует сложной работы над собой и его можно использовать на многих сайтах, комбинируя ширину колонок в пикселах и процентах. Примером такого макета служит сайт Хабрахабр, ширина колонок у него задана в процентах.